# how to count number of outgoing packets using python

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I need to count the number of outgoing packets through `eth0` in Linux.

I tried using the `iptarf` command to do this but i need to result to be in a variable that I can print, I was wondering if the Scapy library can be used to do this.

The result doesn't need to be to accurate I just need this as a way to show that there are outgoing packets and it must be in variable that can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
from scapy.all import *

a=0

def f(packet):
     global a
     a+=1

s=sniff(prn=f, timeout=1, iface=YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME, store=0)

print(a)
```

In this case `timeout` is 1, so it will count the packets in 1 second, you can change it, or put the entire code in a loop to make it count 1 second over and over again.